# JUnit and Ruby test Integration

Tags: java, ruby, eclipse, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have a set of test scripts which were written in Java JUnit using Eclipse and Capture-Replay test scripts for the same application which are in Ruby and were generated using MarathonITE. I am going to create a new Eclipse application that will take in one JUnit script, one Ruby script, combine them into a Text file and display them.

For the next step in my project I would like to get a little bit of help to get a good understanding of my system and what can be done with it:

1) Is it possible to run all my JUnit tests in the folder and print them in the same text file rather than running them one by one? Is it wise to do that?

2) How can I integrate the Java tests and Ruby tests into one system? That is, is there a way to run the tests simultaneously/ one after another but put them into one output that accepts both Java and Ruby? I have been looking into JRuby but I have no idea on how to integrate them together. I would prefer integrating the Ruby scripts into my Java files rather than the other way round because my project will be implemented in Java. A little more insight on this topic would be good.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

there's maven plugins for that: **de.saumya.mojo:runit-maven-plugin**

here's an example how to run ruby tests (using rake, it's also possible to run without) and quite more on JRuby-Rack's [pom.xml](https://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack/blob/master/pom.xml#L260-L286) ... runit plugin is just one way using built-in unit testing libraries.